# Make Stream Deck work with DaVinci Resolve

Tags: windows, video-editing, productivity, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an Elgato [Stream Deck XL](https://www.elgato.com/en/stream-deck-xl) and I thought it would make my life easier. However, it turns out, it's a lot of work before it makes your life easier.

The most frustrating thing is when the hotkeys of the stream deck do not match the application any more because the application is in a different state than the Stream Deck thinks.

I am now trying to make video editing with Blackmagic Design [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) easier. While an Icon Pack exists, it is, well, just an icon pack which does nothing.

What I need is something that actually works, e.g.

- a Plugin for Stream Deck which interacts with DaVinci Resolve
- a Plugin for DaVinci Resolve which interacts with Stream Deck
- a 3rd party software which brings them together

It must

- work on Windows 10
- work with a German keyboard Layout
- come with more than the only 70 icons. I am assuming that we can have the full 32 buttons on each of the 8 main pages (Media, Cut, Edit, Fusion, Color, Fairlight, Deliver), giving a total of at least 240 icons + keyboard mappings

What I found so far:

- [Sideshow FX Stream Deck Profile](https://www.sideshowfx.net/stream-deck-profile-davinci) which does not work for me, because it needs an English keyboard layout. They claim to have more than 1000 icons and shortcuts BTW.

I am not sure about the price. It seems I have to spend at least 35 USD for getting a decent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sideshow FX is the best bet you have. You just have to take some patience and re-program the shortcuts that works for you. I did something similar, It's not difficult, but tedious work.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is the profile I'm currently using and I'm very satisfied with it: [Color Grading](https://www.mauriziomercorella.com/davinci-resolve-stream-deck-profile).

It has full compatibility on both Windows and Mac and it comes in 2 version for both Stream Deck and Stream Deck XL so you're basically set for life.

This is a pre made profile tho so you don't need to create your own profile from scratch which is great as I don't want to waste my time creating a professional profile from scratch.

To import the profile:

1. go to settings
2. select the "Profile" tab
3. on the dropdown arrow, select import
4. select the `.streamdeckprofile` file matching your stream deck

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners. They are often associated with spam.

Comment: Either the StreamDeck software is bullshit or this profile is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJRus.png I paid 27 € for this. Please send me a screenshot on how it looks on your PC.

Comment: Okay, the icons were a bug of StreamDeck 6.0.3. With 6.0.4 I get correct icons. About "basically set for life": that profile consists of only 27 actions, many of which are not helpful and/or I can't even figure out what they do. It's not even possible to do basic actions such as selecting "Cut" or "Fusion" page. I want my money back.